# Export .csv file from Datatable Or List in c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had seen many solution to export csv file using either StringBuilder and Foreach.
but nobody can describe what will happens when following condition will come?

But my question is what happens when contains comma(,) into field value?
I want export data with comma(,) value

Before giving answer please read carefully my question. For more help i giving you an example table as given below.

**Example table:**

```
Field-1                Field-2                      Field-3
Dummy data             27 Oct, 2012                 Mark,David,Nancy etc...
Dummy data             27 Oct, 2012                 Mark,David,Nancy etc...
Dummy data             27 Oct, 2012                 Mark,David,Nancy etc...
Dummy data             27 Oct, 2012                 Mark,David,Nancy etc...
Dummy data             27 Oct, 2012                 Mark,David,Nancy etc...
And so on......
```

I want export above data into .csv file.
Also i want export exact value.
 **Not with double quote e.g "27 Oct, 2012" NOT VALID**

Comment: You can use double quotes to surround the values in a field with commas - i.e., "27 Oct, 2012" or "Mark,David,Nancy etc..."

Comment: Thanks tim for ur reply, but double quotes will display into exported .csv file.

Comment: CSV is a very basic format and double-quoting fields with commas is the correct solution for your situation.  Is there a reason you don't want the quotes to show in the CSV file?  Most CSV readers (if not all) will know how to handle them properly.

Comment: Yes, because i have one project task its already in php and my task is convert into .net. Client simply ask me if php can do the why .net can't?

Comment: If you know the values in the field (i.e, you know that Oct 27, 2012 is one field), then you can simply write it out that way.  I'm a little confused as to exactly what the problem is - you can write whatever you want to the file.  Can you post some of your code?  That might make it a little clearer.

Comment: I never know what data will come because it is dynamic data will come from database. I fill datable using sqldataadapter and simply run foreach with filled datable and write the into. Assume that i have passed all download header in response. Response.Write("data"). I will post my code soon

Comment: Neither PHP nor .NET can handle random data with comma's without something like double quotes or another separator.

Answer (score 1):

<del>You should enclose fields with commas in double quotes. If the quoted field values contains double quotes, use **double** double quotes in their place.</del>

In your case:

```
Dummy data,"27 Oct, 2012","Mark,David,Nancy"
Dummy data,"27 Oct, 2012","Mark,David ""the CSV wiz"",Nancy"
```

Also, web search.

EDIT: after your comment against double quotes, you'll have to parse it manually and take the known comma positions into account, but that will only work if there is only one field with an arbitrary number of commas and it comes last (or you parse the data from both sides and take the remainder as that field).

If you have no way of deterministic comma parsing, then use another delimiter, like the Tab. Something that cannot be in the input, basically.

Comment: No, i want display exact value. Double quotes will display into .csv file

Comment: If you display exact values, then any CSV reader will assume that each comma denotes a new field.  Why are you against double quotes being in the CSV file?